# How to create backlink raster for Cost Distance tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have two polygon shapefiles and one cost surface. I need to estimate accessibility to these two sets of destinations. The part that I don't understand is whether I have to use an output backlink raster in Cost Distance tool or not and what exactly it should be...

It says it's optional to use it, but somehow I have the feeling I should use it.

How do I create an output backlink raster?

I have read the description in ArcMap 10.0 help section, it just that I don't really understand it.

Comment: Check out [costpath analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000019000000) in the help files. The requirements to get the actual path, and hence, its length etcetera are explained there.

Comment: I have read the help files, I just don`t understand them...

*"The output cost back-link raster contains values of 0 through 8, which define the direction or identify the next neighboring cell (the succeeding cell) along the least accumulative cost path from a cell to reach its least cost source."*

How do I create this backlink raster?

Comment: It looks like your question has changed slightly so I am going to move the one from your comment into its title and remove one from its body to see if more focus can get it answered.

Answer (score 1):

You take your Cost surface (values equal cost per map unit, not pixel) and create a Cost Distance surface and a Backlink surface from your **start point** with the Spatial Analyst function "Cost Distance".
Then you take your **destination point** and the just created Cost Distance surface and the Backlink surface and use it in the "Cost Path" function.